# Moodle SQL assignment result/status

Tags: sql, moodle

I got this SQL code from Moodle [SQL scripts](https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/ad-hoc_contributed_reports#Learner_report_by_Learner_with_grades) How to make the result to include all itemnames whether it has a score or not?  **prefix_grade_grade** table contains the score
**prefix_grade_items** table has the itemnames
Not sure what vendor, these scripts are used in Moodle LMS open source system

```
SELECT u.firstname AS 'Name' , u.lastname AS 'Surname', c.fullname AS 'Course', cc.name AS 'Category', 
CASE WHEN gi.itemtype = 'Course'    
THEN c.fullname + ' Course Total'  
ELSE gi.itemname 
END AS 'Item Name', ROUND(gg.finalgrade / gg.rawgrademax * 100 ,2) AS Percentage

FROM prefix_course AS c 
JOIN prefix_context AS ctx ON c.id = ctx.instanceid 
JOIN prefix_role_assignments AS ra ON ra.contextid = ctx.id 
JOIN prefix_user AS u ON u.id = ra.userid 
JOIN prefix_grade_grades AS gg ON gg.userid = u.id 
JOIN prefix_grade_items AS gi ON gi.id = gg.itemid 
JOIN prefix_course_categories AS cc ON cc.id = c.category 
WHERE gi.courseid = c.id AND gi.itemname != 'Attendance' AND gi.itemmodule != 'scorm'
ORDER BY `Name` ASC
```

Comment: You should provide some description to tables we can use (which one contains score, which one contains itemnames?). And define DB vendor.

Comment: Some data and expected output go long way to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably just switch the JOIN around for the grade_grades and grade_items and then do a LEFT JOIN on the grade_grades. I would also move the WHERE condition to the gi JOIN:

```
JOIN prefix_grade_items AS gi ON gi.courseid = c.id AND gi.itemname != 'Attendance' AND gi.itemmodule != 'scorm'
LEFT JOIN prefix_grade_grades AS gg ON gg.userid = u.id AND gg.itemid = gi.id
```

Moodle can use Mysql, Postgresql, MariaDB, SQL Server and Oracle - so the queries are generic. There are some functions available for cross database compatible queries here : https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API#SQL_compatibility_functions

Comment: Good job Russell. Can you do me a last favor, how can I add the submission status of assignment, like Submitted or not Yet?